# Using strings inside quo() and get the expression inside the string itself, in rlang package

Tags: r, string, tidyverse, evaluation

Working with rlang, I would like to obtain the results of quo(just_an_example), while typing quo("just_an_example").
That means that I want to obtain

```
<quosure: global>
~just_an_example
```

but when the expression inside quo() is the string "just_an_example". Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am however not certain of the solution as I am not able to completely understand the question, but it seems you want to have same results even if you enter a quoted string inside `rlang::quo` function. I am using **rlang_0.2.0.9001** version.

You may try this:

```
 library(rlang)

quo(!!as.symbol("just_an_example"))
```

or

`quo(!!sym("just_an_example"))`

**Output**:

```
> quo(!!sym("just_an_example"))
<quosure>
  expr: ^just_an_example
  env:  global
```